# Help identifying characters on a commemorative lighter (Ed.: Identified; 紫微星)

Tags: characters

This is from a lighter I recently found, tucked away in a drawer for years. It's a commemorative lighter, with a picture of Mao Zedong.

[image: Lighter Photograph]

I have identified the middle character as 微, and while I can recognise the radicals on the first character, I'm completely unable to find it in any online dictionaries. The lighter is made in Japan, but from China.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`紫微星`

"紫" in English :    purple; violet
"微" in English :    minute; tiny

• an example from a publication for the youth • [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The characters are 紫微星. 紫微星 and 北极星 are the same, it is Polaris.

紫微星 is named as "Emperor Star", because it seems to be stationary and other stars move around it.